# Looking for this specific font!

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I’m looking to track down this specific font, I’ve tried multiple Find Font websites. the slanted crossbar on the lowercase e and the y and g seperate it from any font i’ve seen.

I believe the websites I tried are WhatTheFont and WhatFontIs. The source is a Squishmallow plushie bio tag specifically, [Janet](https://squishmallows.com/product/janet/)!

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Where did you find this? Is it from a web site? If so, can you provide the link?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not from a website! It is from a brand of stuffed animals called Squishmallows. Each plush has a tag with the character’s name and a short biography, which is what’s pictured above!